# Xcode error "Unable to create a save panel." when creating new Swift file

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I want to create a new Swift file and I get this error... how can I fix this? I'm using Xcode 13.1.

> Unable to create a save panel.
>
> Try your operation again. If that fails, quit and relaunch the application and try again.

[image: Unable to create a save panel.]

Comment: Have you relaunched XCode as advised?

Comment: yes, not working

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried rebooting and reinstalling Xcode but that didn't help. Other file types may be able to progress one more step, but still couldn't finish creating the file. I was able to create a file a couple of days ago and it suddenly failed. I don't recall doing anything special to Xcode except installing the SF Symbol 3.1 update.

Comment: Update: found a workaround for me. If I unplug the external monitor on my MacBook then it works. If I plug it in again then it fails again. Hope that helps.

Comment: I think I have found what did I do that triggered this bug. With my external monitor (non-retina) still attached, I went to System Preferences -> Display, dragged the menu back to the MacBook internal display, restarted Xcode, then the problem went away.

It seems to be related to external non-retina display chosen as the main monitor.

Comment: it worked!, thanks Ryan. You fixed an issue that Xcode support couldn't

Answer (score 2):

Same problem Here.

Thanks to  [Ryan Fung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/998018/ryan-fung) for the Workaround:

> I think I have found what did I do that triggered this bug. With my external monitor (non-retina) still attached, I went to System Preferences -> Display, dragged the menu back to the MacBook internal display, restarted Xcode, then the problem went away. It seems to be related to external non-retina display chosen as the main monitor.

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. But how the heck did you figure that out?

Comment: This did not work for me. Even completely unplugging my external monitor does not help.

Answer (score 2):

I did face the same issue here but in my case I just **Force Quit Xcode** and **Re-Open** it again, and then it's work normally.

Answer (score 1):

Unplugging your external monitor should do the trick. If it doesn't, try restarting Xcode and minimising the window -- this has worked every time for me.